# Making two python programs communicate

Tags: python, multiprocess

I have two python programs running infinitely.

The first process uses Twisted and Autobahn to receive data from a WebSocket feed. **It is an infinite loop.**

The second process uses a custom library to receive data from Pusher WebSocket feed. **It is also an infinite loop.**

I am seeking  for a way to make these two processes communicate with a third process. This third process must be able to communicate **bidirectionally** with both processes. Hence, the third process must be able to **push and receive messages from the two programs**.

I tried to use multiprocessing and Queue but without success.

*This is the first process:*

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol, connectWS
import json

class ClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    ...

    def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
        ...
        # Send data to third process
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = WebSocketClientFactory("wss://feed.com")
    factory.protocol = ClientProtocol
    connectWS(factory)
    reactor.run()
```

*This is the second process:*

```
import pusherclient
import sys, time
import json

def callback(event):
    ...
    # Send data to third process

global pusher


def connect_handler(data):
    channel = pusher.subscribe('order_book')
    channel.bind('data', callback)


...
pusher.connect()

while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: To accomplish this task I'd encourage you to use `pyzmq` which is the Python binding for ZeroMQ. Check it out: http://zeromq.org/bindings:python

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out

Comment: The Queue module only allows to communicate between threads of the same process. ZeroMQ is probably the lightest-weight solution for proper inter-process communication within the same host. (Doing the same using shared files of named pipes is possible, but you'll just end up writing your own message middleware implementation.)

Comment: A highly concise 0MQ + Python intro: https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html

Comment: @9000 Thanks, I'll read it.